# need help in passing URL parameters to variables

Tags: javascript

i need help with a little code that i have below. i'm a newbie in javascript so i hope someone could help me here

i've used the function below to grab parameters from URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gup( name )
 {
 name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
 var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
 var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
 var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
 if( results == null )
  return "";
 else
  return results[1];
 }
</script>
```

now the problem is that i need to set that parameters into variable so i can use that variable into something else.

for instance i have below form:

```
<form method="get" action="#" name="dealer">
   insert dealer code<br />
   <input type="text" name="dcode" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

so whenever i pressed submit button, URL will have parameter. i want to use this parameter as variable. here is the output code

```
var dealer_param = gup( 'dcode' );
document.write(dealer_param);
```

again for instance i have define variables:

```
var a1 = "John Doe"
var a2 = "Jane Doe"
```

now i want to type a1 in the form box and when i pressed submit i want javascript gave me John Doe as the output and not a1 as i'm currently have

i hope it's not much of a confusing question

thanks in advance

~aji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to store the values in an assocuative array instead of individual variables. E.g.

```
var arr;
arr['a1'] = "John Doe";
arr['a2'] = "Jane Doe";

// ...

var dealer_param = gup( 'dcode' );
document.write(arr[dealer_param]);
```

A second approach is to use `eval` - which I personally would recommend against for a variety of reasons including security issues.

```
var a1 = "John Doe"
var a2 = "Jane Doe"

var dealer_param = gup( 'dcode' );
document.write(eval(dealer_param));
```